# How to call a function on every element in a list in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function that takes a List as a parameter. In this function there is another List, which contains data I want to pass into the recursive function. I for every element in the list I want to call the function.

I have tried the following:

```
list2.foreach(foo(_::list1))
```

I get the following error:

```
knight1.scala:78: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: Main.$anon.CW8a.Pos
    (which expands to)  (Int, Int)
    list2.foreach(foo(_::list1))
                       ^
```

Both list1 and list2 are of the type List[(Int, Int)].

Comment: What is the type of `foo` ?

Comment: Does `list2.foreach( pair => foo( pair :: list1 ) )` work?

Comment: This did work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you need to be more explicit. You are misusing the underscore operator.

```
list2.foreach(elt => foo(elt::list1))
```